# What is the difference between NLM vs Open image denoise?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, denoise

What is the difference between NLM vs Open image denoise? also what is the "denoising data" in view layer properties?

Comment: Hello :). NLM (*non-local means*) is an old Blender denoiser. *Open Image Denoiser* is a new advanced denoiser. *Denoising Data* simply allow the *Open Image Denoiser* to be used in the compositor.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice explanation video by *IBN-Blender 3d Artwork*
[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNTDbf3C0fA).

From what I understood:

*Open Image Denoise* and *NLM* are two sorts of denoising modes. *OID* is faster and doesn't need a high sampling rate, it is ideal for animation. *NLM* is slower and needs a higher sampling rate, it is ideal for single image.

You can use *OID* either through the *Render* panel or through the *Compositor*. The second solution gives better results.

For the first solution, enable *OID* through *Properties panel > Render > Sampling > Denoising > Render*.

For the second solution, make sure you've deactivated any denoising in the *Render* panel, then go into *Properties panel > View Layers > Passes > Data*, and activate *Denoising Data*, it will create all the necessary output sockets in the *Compositor Render Layers* node.

Now open the *Compositor*, create a *Filter > Denoise* node, plug the *Nosiy Image, Albedo* and *Normal* output sockets of the *Render Layers* node into the *Denoise*, plug *Denoise* into the *Output* and *Viewer* nodes.

Comment: so can I use OID if I have AMD CPU and GPU?

Comment: I guess so, have you encountered any problem?

Comment: Futher reading: [Type of Denoiser built into Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178257/type-of-denoiser-built-into-blender/178330#178330)

Comment: no, just wondering if I will get the same speed as if I used intel CPU