# Which Denoiser to turn on?

Tags: rendering, denoise

Which denoiser should I use? Does it matter?  1. View Layer Properties Denoiser OR 2. the Intel Open Image Denoise --> which I know is quite powerful. So why use the denoiser under View Layer Properties at all?  Is there a link someone could give so I can better understand the technical side of these denoisers?
Does it matter if I turn both on? (shown in image).

[image]

Then there is the third option 3. Render Properties> Denoise> Render ie. OptiX
[image]

For now also thankful there is options.

UPDATED POST:

I made a short 20 sec video and there seems to be some blotchiness/ jitter. I did lower the Sampling to 25 so I assume that's it. Wondering if someone can take a look?? I share through obviously email for quality sake.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178257/type-of-denoiser-built-into-blender and https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/denoising.html and https://artisticrender.com/how-to-use-intel-denoiser-in-blender/ and https://blenderartists.org/t/big-denoise-test-intel-open-image-denoise-vs-others/1175114/120

Comment: Hello :). To simplify a lot: Use only one of the three denoisers. If you have OptiX, use OptiX, it's the best one :).

Comment: test the 3 different denoisers, OpenImageDenoise is quite good as well, use it in the Compositor rather than in the Render panel

Comment: here is an answer I gave few days ago: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/207779/what-is-the-difference-between-nlm-vs-open-image-denoise

Comment: Low samples will result in artifacts. For animation none of the denoisers will work out of the box, you need a mix of temporal and spatial denoising. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181921/how-to-denoise-animations-using-blenders-temporal-denoiser

Comment: I will check all the advice given, very helpful :)