# How to speed up cycles render times for animation

Tags: animation, mesh, texturing

I'm quite new to blender and 3D in general. I made this character for an academic project.

[image]

I made the materials using mostly the nodes in the shader editor.

lava:

[image]

object:

[image]

this project is supposed to be a 10 to 20 secs animation (I will pick some animation from mixamo), but i noticed that the rendering takes like 18 mins for 1 frame. Is there any way to make this rendering process faster?

I tried changing the render engine to eevee, it takes like 20 seconds, but I lose quality =/

[image]

Comment: This video >https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gSyEpt4-60< by blender guru explains a lot of how to reduce cycles render times.  This video was made for blender 2.79, but almost everything it talks about still applies to 2.8 and onwards

Comment: Duarte, thanks for the reply an thanks for the tips, will be more careful next time.

Ethan, thanks for the reply i will se the video.=)

Comment: also you could try to decrease the sampling value and enable a denoising, but it doesn't work fine with all kind of image. Here is an answer I gave about denoising: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/207779/what-is-the-difference-between-nlm-vs-open-image-denoise

Comment: the denoise realy helped! and also i was rendering with CPU (safe palm...)! thanks to you all for the assistance =D