# Speed up my Rendertimes in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, blend-files

I'm really new to blender but I did a lot of research and testing, but my render times are just bad.
Or rather my rendertimes in a specific file that I created (my first project).

For the scene I need about 1:30h to render. I render on CPU (Ryzen 9 5900x), because my CPU is faster than my GPU (GTX1060 6GB) (and yes I know, GPU render would be better and yes my GPU is a bottleneck, but RTX 3080 is sold out).

I tested the BMW file/ benchmark and have a render time (CPU) of about 1min with adaptive sampling on.

**Can somebody with more knowledge than me please check out my blender file and tell me what I did wrong?**

I already played around with specific render settings (samples, denoise, tilesize, bounces)
Maybe a simple setting is wrong that I just overlooked, because the scene isn't really that complexe (just a single shelf in a room).

To note: I would like to render this image in 4k, so that's intended.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: [blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations may be too high for a 4k image.

Your benchmark of 1 minute for the BMW is very good. Note, however, that the image is rendered with only 35 samples and at 50% size. If you increase the size to 100% the render time will quadruple! Increase the size to 400% and it will be multiplied by 16 again. That's **64 times** longer for 400% than if the size was 50%. **This turns one minute render time into one hour!**

On the other hand, your scene is an indoor scene. Such **interior scenes need much more samples to get rid of the noise.** That's because the light only comes through the window or door and bounces in the room. More samples increase the render time. Light portals can help a bit ([What does Light Portal mean?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33017/what-does-light-portal-mean/33024)).

For preview in high-res you can render only a part of the image with a box selection, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. (To remove the box press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>)

Last but not least you can render nice interior scenes with Eevee, too. Have a look here: [(youtube) How to make Realtime Archviz with Blender and Eevee (Part 1 of 3)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VNztZdfGZY)

[18 Ways to Speed Up Blender Cycles Rendering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gSyEpt4-60) (It's from 2017 but gives you an idea about render times and how to save time)

Comment: Thank you very much. Somebody on reddit also pointed out that I'm actually rendering at 8k (because I've set it to 400%). My initial idea was 1080p * 400% is 4k, but actually only dimensions get multiplied and it comes out to 7680x4320 instaed of my wanted 3840x2160