# weird yellow and red grains on my renders

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, denoise, noise-reduction

I am working on a scene in blender related to Minecraft but for some reason my render image have small yellow and red spots sprinkled which are barely noticeable , is their a way to fix it. it might be a problem with cycles as it works fine with eevee.
[image]

Comment: You can put your comment as part of the question.  Of course it would help to see your image or a small portion with the grains or [noise].  You can reduce your image using a lower resolution output .. potentially.  You might use free GIMP to clip your image.  Have you researched [noise] or looked for the denoising check box?   You may wish to show that in your question as part of a your Blender screen capture.

Comment: ok ill try lowering the resolution

Comment: but iam not sure about the noise modifier.

Comment: GIMP can edit your OpenEXR or PNG.  You might try searching here at BSE .... How do I get rid of noise in cycles render or something like that.

Comment: ok thanks for the help

Comment: To the side of this page with the label [Related] are hopefully your same  or similar question.  So you may see some [hopefully not so] elaborate answer there.  One person called them fireflies

Comment: ok ill check thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles

Answer (score 1):

These are often referred to as "fireflies," and they're a common artifact in Cycles renders. Because Cycles is a path tracing engine which uses pseudo-randomness, some samples will find light sources and illuminate pixels that would otherwise be fairly dim.

You can either increase your number of samples (although it may take a very large number and long render time to eliminate them entirely), or you can take a look  at Blender's relatively new [built-in denoising options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/denoising.html).