# Why is the background so full of noise?

Tags: rendering, animation, smoke-simulation, denoise, noise-reduction

I rendered this animation of a coffee mug with a smoke simulation to create the hot steam but the background is almost distorting like with heat distortion. I do use depth of field and the focus shifts from the mokka to the mug, but the entire kitchen background flickers way to much. The resolution is 1080x1080 at 150% with the standard noise Threshold of 0.01 and 128 samples with a tile size of 256. At first i rendered with 64 samples and then again with 128 but nothing changed.
Does the smoke domain distort in addition to the depth of field option or maybe it has something to do with the animated cloud texture that is used by the smoke emitter?
[Animation result](https://youtube.com/shorts/u9FvZl_Eypc?feature=share)
[project file](https://we.tl/t-dJoYMoDtdA)

Comment: Could you share a screenshot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Comment: a screenshot doesn't show the problem, it only shows in the animation, i linked a youtube shorts video of it

Comment: Try 10 000 samples. That will fix it. It's always samples. If that's not practical , real depth of field is noisy, consider using compositing and blur based on Z pass instead.