# Particle pixels problem

Tags: rendering

I have a big problem with some small pixels inside the bark texture. I tried many times to remove it but nothing.

Here's the render I'm having trouble with: [image]
Here's my Blender file: https://mega.nz/#!gwViVRDI

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Comment: @Matt I don't think is a duplicate of that post. Those look look like fireflies.

Comment: Fireflies are nothing more than "noise in Cycles" and solved by the exact same strategies.

Comment: @Matt not quite. Increasing samples might make fireflies even worse

Comment: Use clamping in the render settings

Comment: @Tix the file linked on the question needs a decription key! Please unlock it so that we can help you.

Comment: @cegaton There is a sampling threshold above which fireflies WILL decrease. For some scenes, that threshold is unreasonably high. The same is exactly true with other kinds of noise. There is a sampling threshold above which noise decreases, and for scenes in which that threshold is too high, the exact same strategies that reduce noise will also reduce fireflies. The math doesn't change.

Comment: @cegaton !10Te3TPxaEtadaeezQlR2VUtnBHz8JsWiKnOMWZNikQ or https://mega.nz/#!gwViVRDI!10Te3TPxaEtadaeezQlR2VUtnBHz8JsWiKnOMWZNikQ

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you're having is what's sometimes called "fireflies." These are not in the texture, these are part of the render. The short answer is "render more samples." "Progressive" can be useful for this. Just let it render the whole image for as long as you can stand. It'll get a little better with each pass, and you can cancel whenever you want and still have a full image.

This is usually just a consequence of the probabilistic nature of the Cycles renderer. I'm going to mark this question as a duplicate, but I want to at least point you in the right direction.

One strategy that's not well documented is to render the same image more than one time, but with a different "seed" value for each image (set in the render settings). Stack these results in an image editor (careful with opacity math) to average them together, and the fireflies will be much less apparent.

Check out this other answer about [why fireflies happen](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41803/why-do-fireflies-increase-with-number-of-samples-when-using-a-hdri-light-source).

Also look at this question about [how to reduce noise](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles).

And lastly, this question about [why Cycles has to cast multiple rays per pixel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/why-cant-cycles-cast-1-ray-per-image-pixel-instead-renders-progressively-to-in).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Enable multiple importance sampling for the world texture.